# Workbox runtime caching doesn't work with url with query parameter?

Tags: javascript, progressive-web-apps, workbox

I have an public API endpoint like this:

https://data.weather.gov.hk/weatherAPI/opendata/weather.php?dataType=warnsum&lang=en

And I want to runtime cache its response with service worker. This is how I defined the route:

```js
registerRoute(
  new RegExp('.+/weatherAPI/opendata/weather.php?dataType=warnsum&lang=en'),
  new StaleWhileRevalidate({
    cacheName: 'weatherApi',
    plugins: [
      new ExpirationPlugin({
        maxAgeSeconds: 60 * 60 * 24
      }),
      new BackgroundSyncPlugin('getWeatherAPI', {
        maxRetentionTime: 24 * 60 // Retry for max of 24 Hours (specified in minutes)
      })
    ]
  })
)
```

However, this doesn't work and the response of this url was not saved into the cache. I wonder if query parameter would be the issue here, or if I have missed something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query parameters are included when performing a `RegExpRoute` match in Workbox.

I think it's more likely that you need to escape the characters that are "special" in a regular expression, like `?`.

Using something other than a regular expression might actually be easier. You can use a [`matchCallback`](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/reference-docs/latest/module-workbox-routing#%7EmatchCallback), for instance, like:

```
registerRoute(
  ({url}) => url.href.endsWith('/weatherAPI/opendata/weather.php?dataType=warnsum&lang=en'),
  new StaleWhileRevalidate({...}),
)
```

Comment: Thank you Jeff it does the trick. One more question, after I have saved it to the cache, would the service worker automatically intercept and cancel my request, if it is made before the cache expired? Do I need to write any code for such behavior?

Comment: Because I still see the request being sent after the cache. Is it because of the caching policy, `StaleWhileRevalidate`?

Comment: Yes, if you use `StaleWhileRevalidate`, there will always be a network request made. You could try `CacheFirst` with the `ExpirationPlugin` instead if you want to avoid the network request until the expiration happens.